# comma needed after conjunction 'and' that separates 2 independent clauses?

Tags: punctuation

Do we need a comma after the conjunction "and" below?

> The umpire made a bad call, and, in the interest of fairness, he reversed his decision.

I think that the following sentence is better with just one comma:

> The umpire made a bad call, and in the interest of fairness he reversed his decision.

I think the same could be said for the following (just one comma):

> She acted like a brat, and quite frankly I think she should be grounded.

Do you agree with my one-comma sentence examples?

Comment: You should ***never*** put a comma both before, and, after *"and"*.

Answer (score 2):

It would be unusual to put a comma there.

The comma before the *and* would be usual; the common practice being that when there are two independent clauses separated by a coördinating conjunction (like *and*) you put a comma before the conjunction.

You could defend the comma after *and* by arguing that that "in the interest of fairness" was parenthetical, if it helped reading, but you aren't looking to defend the not-worth-defending; just drop the comma.

Comment: So do you agree that only one comma is sufficient in both examples? BTW, I love the diaeresis in "coördinating", a la The New Yorker.

Comment: More that sufficient; having one after would be very strange and arguably just wrong. My fondness for diaereses is probably best not copied, but I got into the habit when I was young and impressionable ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a semi colon before the word "and"

Comment: That would be an unusual choice. Semicolons between independent clauses are normally only used if there is no coordinating conjunction, so replacing the *and* with one would be much more normal than following one with *and*.